# My plant is not thriving

Tags: houseplants

[image: sick plant]
We’ve had this plant, I believe it is a philodendron Xanadu, for a couple of months now and it just isn’t adjusting to our home. It is not dying and it continues to make new growth but the leaves continue to turn yellow and fall off. It sits in the middle of the room and the room has a lot of light, just not direct light. 
Any idea why it is not thriving?

Comment: Is this plant in a pot inside a pot?  Hard to tell but we need to know what soil you've transplanted this guy into...Middle of the room does NOT have lots of light.  Foot candles decline rapidly when leaving the window.  The pot thing is bothersome, need to understand what kind of soil you've used, is there any rock or gravel below that soil in the pot?  A huge no no but I'll explain later if you've added rock gravel or sand to this pot.  How do you know when to water?  Most of all have you added a balanced fertilizer?  That bleaching of the leaves is saying something has been added not good..

Comment: Your plant needs to be closer to the window, as close as possible without direct sunlight through the window.  I am thinking this plant was in a 'peat pot' type pot and you planted in the larger pot and left the peat pot thingy in place, yes?

Comment: How long ago was this plant transplanted in this pot?  It is clay yes?  I am already seeing salt deposits from your tap water.  Is this a clay pot?  How long ago did you plant this plant in this larger pot?  Or did someone else do this?  Salt deposits and tap water aren't necessarily a deal breaker but that white stuff on the outside of your pot is telling me your water has a lot of salts, chlorine, fluoride (I am being good not going into THAT subject; fluoride right now). Have you used fertilizer?  Tell us about the pot within a pot thingy...?  How do you water?

Comment: Did you move this plant for a short while close to the window or did you take it out of doors in the bright sunlight for awhile?  Looks like a bit of sunburn actually...

Comment: We've had the plant since Christmas. It was in a plastic pot and we transplanted it into this clay pot. What looks like another pot inside is just a root that is wraps around. The soil is just an organic planting soil form a bag. We did try a fertilizer at one point but it didn't do anything. All of the pots in the house have these white deposits on the outside, and this is the only one that is not thriving. We have never put in it direct sunlight, and never outside.

Comment: A root?  Just love trying to help people with plants by looking at photos...arggggh.  Good.  Get that plant nearer a window.  These guys can handle low light but that means the low light out of doors, not indoors.  Do you have a covered patio?  Your water is full of salts, that is what you are seeing on the outside of your pots.  Just means you will need to transplant your plants into fresh potting soil and cleaning the deposits off the pot once a year.  You do have to give a little fertilizer, don't expect to see fast 'results' but all plants need fertilizer.  Did your soil come with fert?

Comment: Potting soil from a bag...perfect. As long as it did not have added fertilizer or water holding gimmicks.  Perfect.  Did you put rocks or gravel beneath the soil and over the hole in the bottom of your pot?

Comment: No, no rocks or gravel. I will give moving it closer to the window a try. I don't think the soil came with fertilizer so I will pick up some at the nursery. Thank you.

Comment: Try to make sure there was no fertilizer in that soil...look for the old bag?   ha ha or look for another one at the nursery?  This guy needs to be right beside a window, out of direct sunlight coming through the glass for now.  Any further from the window the light is worthless to this plant.  http://www.theledlight.com/lumens.html/  keep in touch this site is not a one answer answers all type of site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a 'good' spot near a window, (the middle of the room is not sufficient),even if it gets some morning sun it won't burn. Check your watering habits.Try not to move it inside and out,sudden temperature changes will make a plant 'crash'. Nice plant!

Comment: Thanks. We moved it closer to the window and we will see how it goes.

Comment: Cut that bleached leaf off the plant right by the main trunk.  That leaf is unable to do any photosynthesis so is unable to 'pay' for its upkeep by the main plant.  Water deeply when you water and do not water again until that whole pot and plant and soil are obviously lighter to lift.  A little fertilizer is critical...balanced, boring simple fertilizer.  Indoor plants need less fertilizer than out of door plants, less light to use for manufacturing food for the plant.  Osmocote 14-14-14 use half of recommendations.